# python - saving vector-array data with different lengths at columns of a txt file

Tags: python, saving-data

I have two sets of data as

```
A=[array([1,2,3]),array([1,2,3,4]), ... array([11,13,2,1,5,7,9,0])]
B=[array([11,21,31]),array([16,27,38,48]), ... array([114,134,24,14,54,74,94,04])]
```

I want to save the arrays as consecutive x-y columns in a txt file such as:
[image]
in which the columns of A and B data are consequantly written.

However, because of different lenghts, I can not apply the command:
`np.savetxt(np.transpose(A)`.
Any help is appreciated.

I tried using `np.savetxt(np.transpose)` but here the columns have different lengths and this command fails.

Comment: Have you considered filling shorter arrays with np.nan?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) + [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) to generate the desired format with flexibility:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

A = [np.array([1,2,3]),
     np.array([1,2,3,4]),
     np.array([11,13,2,1,5,7,9,0])]
B = [np.array([11,21,31]),
     np.array([16,27,38,48]),
     np.array([114,134,24,14,54,74,94,4])]

tmp = (pd
   .concat(map(pd.DataFrame, [A, B]))
   .sort_index(kind='stable').T
   .convert_dtypes().astype(object).fillna('')
)

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(tabulate(tmp, showindex=False, numalign='left', tablefmt='plain'))
```

Output:

```
1  11  1  16  11  114
2  21  2  27  13  134
3  31  3  38  2   24
       4  48  1   14
              5   54
              7   74
              9   94
              0   4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But my windows OS system doesn't know "tabulate". Do you know any way to circumvent the command "tabulate"?

Comment: @H.Khani it's an external library. You have to install it with pip: `pip install tabulate`

Comment: I intalled using `pip install tabulate` in cmd, but stil I have the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It resolved using `%pip install tabulate` in jupyter.